C++ incomplete type used in nested name specifier when using boost::multi_index
I have the following files:
"declaration.hpp"
namespace ns {
    
class Derived;
using DerivedPtr = std::unique_ptr<Derived>;
 
}

"Base.hpp"
namespace ns {

class User;

class Base
{
public:
    uint64_t foo() const;
};

}

"Derived.hpp"
namespace ns {

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    uint64_t bar() const;
};

}

"User.hpp"
#include "declaration.hpp"
namespace ns {
class User
{
private:
    std::map<uint64_t, DerivedPtr>  map;
};

}

I tried to change the map in User to be a multi index map, i.e in "declaration.hpp" I put
struct Foo{};
struct Bar{};
  
using Map = boost::multi_index_container<
        DerivedPtr,
        boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<Foo>,
                boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Base, uint64_t, &Base::foo> >,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<Bar>,
                boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Derived, uint64_t, &Derived::bar> > > >;

and
#include "declaration.hpp"
namespace ns {
class User
{
private:
    Map  map;
};

}

but I get error: incomplete type 'ns::Derived' named in nested name specifier .
I can't put #include "Derived.hpp" & #include "Base.hpp" in "declaration.hpp"
because then I get error: member access into incomplete type due to the forward declaration in "Base.hpp".
Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Is it possible to use fixed values for indices, thus eliminating the need for the member functions?

I don't know for sure, but I would guess that the phrase  &Derived::bar is your main problem, if Derived is not fully defined. Is it possible to write a wrapper type for boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Derived, uint64_t, &Derived::bar> which you could extern and derive later?

Where in "Derived.hpp" is #include "Base.hpp"? Why you have class User; in Base.hpp?

Derived.hpp wasn't included and you need a set of boost headers.
This works:
Live On Compiler Explorer

File ./Base.cpp
 #include "Base.hpp"

 namespace ns {
     uint64_t Base::foo() const { return 9; }
 } // namespace ns


File ./Base.hpp
 #pragma once
 #include <cstdint>

 namespace ns {
     class User;

     class Base {
       public:
         uint64_t foo() const;
     };

 } // namespace ns


File ./Derived.cpp
 #include "Derived.hpp"

 namespace ns {
     uint64_t Derived::bar() const { return 42; }
 } // namespace ns


File ./Derived.hpp
 #pragma once
 #include "Base.hpp"
 namespace ns {

     class Derived : public Base {
       public:
         uint64_t bar() const;
     };

 } // namespace ns


File ./User.cpp
 #include "User.hpp"

 namespace ns {
     void User::do_something() {
         map.emplace(std::make_unique<Derived>());
         map.emplace(std::make_unique<Derived>());
     }
 } // namespace ns


File ./User.hpp
 #include "Derived.hpp"
 #include "declaration.hpp"
 #include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
 #include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
 #include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
 #include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
 // #include <map>

 namespace ns {
     namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
     using Map     = boost::multi_index_container<
         DerivedPtr,
         bmi::indexed_by<bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct Foo>,                                     //
                                             bmi::const_mem_fun<Base, uint64_t, &Base::foo>>,          //
                         bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct Bar>,                                 //
                                                 bmi::const_mem_fun<Derived, uint64_t, &Derived::bar>> //
                         >>;

     class User {
       public:
         void do_something();

       private:
         // std::map<uint64_t, DerivedPtr> map;
         Map map;
     };

 } // namespace ns


File main.cpp
 #include "User.hpp"

 int main() {
     ns::User user;

     user.do_something();
 };



BONUS: C++17 key extraction
Live On Compiler Explorer
using Map     = boost::multi_index_container<
    DerivedPtr,
    bmi::indexed_by<bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct Foo>, bmi::key<&Base::foo>>,
                    bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct Bar>, bmi::key<&Derived::bar>>>>;


Took some doing, but here it is running Live On Compiler Explorer

As a bonus, from c++17 the indexing key extractors can be greatly simplified: https://godbolt.org/z/8saWsxKWv

CMake running version on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/eT7Yjvdxs

Cheers @MarekR. Is "the_executable" a special name, or does Godbolt somehow guess the CMake target to execute? [Perhaps the "Program returned: 0" is merely confusing printing the build process exit code]

this is defined in CMakeLists.txt. CMake can have multiple targets and this hints godbolt which one should be run. If you click "templates/CMake"  it uses the_executable too.
